# android Studio Logcat not working while debugging on HUAWEI Phone

Tags: logcat, huawei-mobile-services, android-studio-3.5.1

My Logcat stopped working with my "developer device" Huawei Y5.

I use Android 3.5.1 fully updated, until two days ago all was working fine, now suddenly my App logs dont show up anymore. The logcat shows the following errors:

```
2019-10-18 08:25:32.075 7043-7074/com.android.example.contentresolvercheck E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2019-10-18 08:25:32.141 7043-7099/com.android.example.contentresolvercheck E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@cb81960
2019-10-18 08:25:32.195 7043-7099/com.android.example.contentresolvercheck E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@9623ede
```

And later (I think on every Log entry):

```
2019-10-18 08:25:33.031 7043-7157/com.android.example.contentresolvercheck E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the AP log switch before? If not, try follow this:

1. Touch the phone icon on the phone.
2. Enter *#*#2846579#*#*.
3. Access the project menu and click Background Settings.
4. Select AP Log Settings.
5. Open the AP log setting page.
6. Click Open to view the log.